# Quick Sort Recursion Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to code Quick Sort using recursion but I am getting a stack overflow error. this the second recursive function is giving that continuous error. I'm just unable to figure it out.

```
public class QuickSortRec {
public static void quicksort(int input[],int a,int b)
{
    if(a<b)
    {
        int pivotpos=partition(input,a,b);
        quicksort(input, a,pivotpos-1);
        quicksort(input, pivotpos+1,b);
    }
}
private static int partition(int input[],int a,int b)
{
    int pivot=input[a];
    int count=0;
    for(int i=a+1;i< input.length;i++)
    {
        if(input[i]<pivot)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    int temp=input[a];
    input[a]=input[count];
    input[count]=temp;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        if(input[i]>pivot)
        {
            for(int j=input.length-1;j>pivot;j--)
            {
                if(input[j]<pivot)
                {
                    temp=input[i];
                    input[i]=input[j];
                    input[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    int arr[]={6,2,10,8,15,3,4};
    int a=0;
    int b=arr.length-1;
    quicksort(arr,a,b);
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes. For example you never used `b` in your pivot function.
You must change your `partition` function same as below:

```java
public class QuickSortRec {
    public static void quicksort(int input[],int a,int b)
    {
        if(a<b)
        {
            int pivotpos=partition(input, a,b);
            quicksort(input, a,pivotpos-1);
            quicksort(input, pivotpos+1,b);
        }
    }

    private static int partition(int arr[],int low,int high)
    {
        int pivot = arr[high];
        int i = (low-1); // index of smaller element
        for (int j=low; j<high; j++)
        {
            // If current element is smaller than or
            // equal to pivot
            if (arr[j] <= pivot)
            {
                i++;

                // swap arr[i] and arr[j]
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }

        // swap arr[i+1] and arr[high] (or pivot)
        int temp = arr[i+1];
        arr[i+1] = arr[high];
        arr[high] = temp;

        return i+1;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int arr[]={6,2,10,8,15,3,4};
        int a=0;
        int b=arr.length-1;
        quicksort(arr,a,b);
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to debug your programm, but didnt realy find a solution for the problem so I decided to try to write my own solution because the task seems very interesting to me.

So my goal was to avoid loops completly and only use recursion:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int   array[]     = { 6, 2, 10, 8, 15, 3, 4 };
    int[] sortedArray = quicksort(array);
    
    for (int currentNumber : sortedArray)
    {
        System.out.print(currentNumber + " ");
    }
}

static int index = 0;
static int tempIndex;

private static int[] quicksort(int[] inputArray)
{
    tempIndex = index;
    int totalArrayLength = inputArray.length;
    if (index != totalArrayLength - 1)
    {
        if (inputArray[index] > inputArray[index + 1])
        {
            int temporary = inputArray[index + 1];
            inputArray[index + 1] = inputArray[index];
            inputArray[index] = temporary;
            quickSort2(inputArray);
        }
        index++;
        quicksort(inputArray);
    }
    return inputArray;
    }

    private static void quickSort2(int[] inputArray)
    {
    if (tempIndex != 0 && inputArray[tempIndex] < inputArray[tempIndex - 1])
    {
        if (tempIndex != 0)
        {
            int temporary2 = inputArray[tempIndex];
            inputArray[tempIndex] = inputArray[tempIndex - 1];
            inputArray[tempIndex - 1] = temporary2;
            tempIndex--;
            quickSort2(inputArray);
        }
    }
}
```